How to increase throttle limit in Spring Batch 5
prior to spring batch 5, we used .throttleLimit(10) to increase the default limit from 4 to 10.
Sample implementation before batch 5:
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor getJobTaskExecutor() {
  ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new       ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
  taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
  taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
  return taskExecutor;
}

Than use is in our step to fully utilize 10 threads
@Bean
public Step sampleStep(TaskExecutor taskExecutor, JobRepository       jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager)     {
  return new StepBuilder("sampleStep", jobRepository)
            .<String, String>chunk(100, transactionManager)
            .reader(itemReader())
            .writer(itemWriter())
            .taskExecutor(getJobTaskExecutor)
            .throttleLimit(10)
            .build();
 }

However, with spring batch 5, throttleLimit is deprecated. According to the doc, we should instead use RepeatOperations to achieve the same. But I'm just struggling to find any valid example to do so

The throttle limit is deprecated, but you can continue to use it as is for now until the issue is fixed. There is no replacement for the current RepeatOperations implementation.
